# Git post-checkout - how to reject push if Composer installation fails

Tags: git, bash, composer-php, githooks

So I've set up a post-checkout hook on my server that will run Composer

```
#!/bin/sh
# Composer Git Checkout Hook

PROJECT_NAME=example.com

cd /home/www/$PROJECT_NAME/htdocs

unset GIT_DIR

# Process composer.json if one exists.
if [ -f composer.json ]
then
    echo "Processing Composer"

    # Run the composer install
    composer.phar install
fi
```

When deploying, it works. However, since is a new server and I've forgotten to enable the cURL module, it fails the installation, yet accepts the push.

```
$ git push deploy master

Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 348 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing Composer
remote: Loading composer repositories with package information
remote: Installing dependencies from lock file
remote: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
remote: 
remote:   Problem 1
remote:     - Installation request for facebook/php-sdk dev-master -> satisfiable by facebook/php-sdk dev-master.
remote:     - facebook/php-sdk dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
remote: 
To ssh://adam@my-server.net/home/www/example.com/git
   0fa8a61..afa63ae  master -> master
```

How do I get the status of the Composer installation and exit so that the remote repository rejects the push?

Answer (score 2):

First, there's an issue with your setup. If `deploy` is a non-bare repo and the master branch is checked out (which I assume), you can't push to that repo. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked).

If you want to be able to reject a push, you need to do so in either the `pre-receive` or `update` [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks). You could use these to check whether or not the Composer config file has changed (in which case it would be in a commit), as is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569960/git-pre-receive-hook). Running Composer itself would require a checkout, or at least the config file. Running Composer  will slow down the commit process, because git has to wait until Composer has finished before it can report back to the client. Note that this is also the case for post-receive hooks, even though they cannot reject the push.

What you could do is use the `update` hook, check if that contains an updated `composer.json` in the master branch using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569960/git-pre-receive-hook), and if it does then run Composer with the updated file to find out if it contains errors. You could create a folder specifically for that purpose. I don't have Composer at hand at the moment. but the return value of the process would normally be `0` for success and non-zero for failure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. As for your concern about the deploy repo, I ran `git init --bare` on /home/www/example.com/git and the actual source files are checked-out to /home/www/example.com/htdocs on post-receive. I thought this was the correct way to do it, or am I mistaken?

Comment: That is the correct way :) I would probably store the git repo outside of the www folder myself, but that's a different issue.