# Can I, in the pre-receive hook, get a list of files that are being pushed to the remote repository?

Tags: git, githooks

I need to write a `pre-receive` hook script which get the information about the files that are being pushed into the server.

I want to know if the list of files that are being pushed into the remote repository can be obtained by a script present in the remote repository

For information, I need to access these files in order to perform some code style checks on them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git pre-receive hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569960/git-pre-receive-hook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server for that hook you are passed in a ref and an old sha and a new sha.  Just use `git diff --name-only old..new` to  get the file list from within the hook

Comment: Note that the hook gets a proposed SHA-1 update which is not the same as saying that there is one commit to be added: the update could remove one commit and add three, for instance.  But yes, you can diff any specific pair of commits (including old-SHA1 vs new-SHA1).

Comment: Right - this was obviously way simplified.  For instance, if there was no previous SHA (new branch) you would need to diff against the NULL tree.  Or if you want it per commit for you would to cycle through output of `git rev-list`, etc.